# Unable to serialize and set DebuggerDisplayAttribute(s) for container class

Tags: .net, debugging, containers, c++-cli

I'm doing a vector implementation for a project with a custom memory manager with pre-allocated memory chunks, and I have pretty much succeeded in making said vector perform the basic functionalities like push_back, erase, reserve, begin() and end() to allow for each loops, and so on, but hovering the thing sadly (and expectadly) simply shows the first object pointed towards and nothing else.

While not strictly nessecary, it'd still be extremely helpful to be able to hover this implementation as if it were a regular std::vector. Is this something that is possible to do? I've found some pages about custom properties for variables in visual studio specifically but failed to really implement them.

I've provided the code as it currently stands at the bottom of the question. The only important part of the code for this question, I think at least, is the top. When trying to compile, I get three errors: E2020 - the managed nullptr type cannot be used here, C2337 - 'Serializable': attribute not found, and C2337'NonSerialized': attribute not found (this one for every member variable). If I remove [Serializable] above the class declaration, I get C3115 'System::Diagnostics::DebuggerDisplayAttribute': this attribute is not allowed on 'ML_Vector' instead of the Serializable error.

I have added /clr to the project at the Common Language RunTime support fields.

This seems to be a rather obscure topic as I've not really found any videos explaining the subject, and have no idea were to go from here.

```
#pragma once
#include "MemLib\MemLib.hpp"
#include <cinttypes>
#include <stdexcept>

#ifdef _DEBUG
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
#endif // _DEBUG
template<typename T>
#ifdef _DEBUG
[Serializable]
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute("Size={m_size}")] // Supposed to act as a proof of concept
struct ML_Vector
{
private:
    // Pool pointer to internal data
    [NonSerialized]
    PoolPointer<T> m_data;
    // Due to our memory usage restriction, a size larger than 2^30 would be guaranteed to exceed memory limits
    [NonSerialized]
    uint32_t m_size = 0;
    // Due to our memory usage restriction, a size larger than 2^30 would be guaranteed to exceed memory limits
    [NonSerialized]
    uint32_t m_capacity = 0;
    // size of the internal type
    [NonSerialized]
    uint16_t m_tSize = 0;
#else // _DEBUG
struct ML_Vector
{
private:
    // Pool pointer to internal data
    PoolPointer<T> m_data;
    // Due to our memory usage restriction, a size larger than 2^30 would be guaranteed to exceed memory limits
    uint32_t m_size = 0;
    // Due to our memory usage restriction, a size larger than 2^30 would be guaranteed to exceed memory limits
    uint32_t m_capacity = 0;
    // size of the internal type
    uint16_t m_tSize = 0;
#endif

public:
    T* begin() const
    {
        return &(m_data[0]);
    }

    T* end() const
    {
        return &(m_data[m_size]);
    }

    const uint32_t& size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    const PoolPointer<T>& data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    // Reserve a new capacity for the vector
    uint32_t reserve(const uint32_t& capacity)
    {
        if (capacity < m_capacity)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Capacity too small! ML_Vector.reserve() cannot be called to reduce the capacity of the vector!");
            std::terminate();
        }

        // Provide a temporary copy of the data
        T* temp = (T*)MemLib::spush(m_capacity * m_tSize);
        std::memcpy(temp, &(*m_data), m_capacity * m_tSize);

        // Free the old pool pointer and allocate a new one
        MemLib::pfree(m_data);
        m_data = MemLib::palloc(capacity);

        // Copy the data over to the new location and pop the temp from the stack
        std::memcpy(&(*m_data), temp, m_capacity * m_tSize);
        MemLib::spop();

        // Inform the new capacity
        return m_capacity = capacity;
    };

    // Clear the vector
    void clear()
    {
        // No need to actually clear data, just setting the size to 0 is enough
        m_size = 0;
    }

    // Push an item into the back of the vector, returns the index of that item
    uint32_t push_back(const T& item)
    {
        // if the capacity of the vector is less than the size of the vector, reserve a larger chunk of memory
        if (m_capacity <= m_size + 1)
        {
            reserve(m_capacity * 2);
        }

        // Set data at location
        m_data[m_size] = item;

        // Return the index of the newly pushed object
        return m_size++;
    };

    // Remove an item in the vecotr by index
    // This operation is much slower than pop_back, and should not be used if pop_back could simply be used instead
    uint32_t erase(const uint32_t& idx)
    {
        if (idx < 0 || m_size <= idx)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Index provided for ML_Vector is out of range!");
            std::terminate();
        }

        // Overwrite
        std::memcpy(&(m_data[idx]), &(m_data[idx + 1]), (m_size - idx) * m_tSize);

        return --m_size;
    };

    // Pop and return the back most item of the vector
    T pop_back()
    {
        if (m_size <= 0)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range exception for ML_Vector at pop_back(), vector already empty!");
            std::terminate();
        }

        // No need to actually remove the data in any "real" way, just mark it as empty
        return m_data[--m_size];
    };

    T& operator*()
    {
        return (*m_data);
    };

    T& operator[](const uint32_t& idx)
    {
        if (idx < 0 || m_size <= idx)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Index provided for ML_Vector is out of range!");
            std::terminate();
        }

        return m_data[idx];
    };

    ML_Vector& operator=(const ML_Vector& other)
    {
        if (false == m_data.IsNullptr())
            MemLib::pfree(m_data);
        m_data = other.m_data;
        m_capacity = other.m_capacity;
        m_size = other.m_size;
        m_tSize = other.m_tSize;

        return *this;
    }

    // Initiate an ML_Vector<T> with a number of T objects, can be called as such to emulate normal C++ style coding
    // ML_Vector<T>() = { args };
    template<typename... Types>
    ML_Vector(Types... args)
    {
        // Set capacity
        m_capacity = sizeof...(args);

        // Allocate to memory pool
        if (false == m_data.IsNullptr())
            MemLib::pfree(m_data);
        m_data = MemLib::palloc(m_capacity);

        // Set the individual item size
        m_tSize = sizeof(T);

        // Set items
        for (auto item : { args... } )
        {
            /*T test = item;*/
            push_back(item);
            //ZeroMemory(item, sizeof(item));
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this via simply giving up on System::Diagnostics and instead finding out about .natvis files. I added one to the project (add new item -> Visual C++ -> Utility -> Debugger Visualization File).

The following code works well enough for now, and at the very least lets us see the internal structure behind the double pointer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
<Type Name="ML_Vector&lt;*&gt;">
    <!--<DisplayString>{{ size={_Mylast - _Myfirst} }}</DisplayString>-->
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[Size]" ExcludeView="simple">m_size</Item>
        <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">m_capacity</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>m_size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>*(m_data.m_pp)</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```